# Accessibility Inspector not working on Xcode 11.x, iOS 13.x on MacOS Catalina & Mojave

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, accessibility, ios13, xcode11

I am unable to inspect any elements using the Accessibility Inspector on iOS 13.2 and higher simulators running on Mac OS Mojave or Catalina. Has anyone else also encountered this issue and if so, is there a solution to this? I did not encounter this issue on iOS 12 Simulators, though.

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123690

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/127247

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/126916

Answer (score 6):

> Has anyone else also encountered this issue and if so, is there a solution to this?

Yes, everyone else has encountered this issue (I provided some links, in comments, showing people complaining about the problem), and no, there is no known standard solution.

Comment: @Badrinath  Not as far as I know. Accessibility is hosed. Did you try the 11.4 beta?

Answer (score 5):

I was encountering a persistent crash when launching the Accessibility Inspector via Spotlight/Alfred. However, if I launch the tool from within Xcode it launches fine and allows me to interact with the Simulator.

From the menu bar:

```
Xcode
  -> Open Developer Tool
     -> Accessibility Inspector
```

Comment: I have his issue as of Xcode 12.5.1 And Big Sur 11.5 - this fixed it thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been resolved for good with Xcode 11.4.1

Please upgrade to that version if you are still facing accessibility inspector issues.

Comment: Xcode 11.5 ios 12 simulator still has this problem, IOS 13 works as expected

Comment: Just to add that it fails with Xcode 11.5 in iOS 12 simulators and tested in macOS 10.15.5 and 10.15.6.

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be resolved with macOS 10.15.2 when using a simulator running iOS 13.3 or higher.

Below that version, the solution is to use a simulator running iOS 12.x

Comment: I am still seeing this issue on the version mentioned above by you.